# Can i use abp template with NET Core or FULL NET core with Angular Js 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

After version 3.0, support for NET 4.6.1 and AngularJs 1.x will stop, I'm right?

So, can i use angularjs 1.x with NET Core + EF Core?

Comment: What?? What does it has to do angular with .NET?

Comment: Is it true that after 2018, new VW cars will no longer support listening to Country stations on the radio?

Answer (score 0):

angular has nothing to do with .net framework version so you can use angular with .net core + ef core